# In the quest 'Berangar's Secrets', how do I go see Coleman if he is dead?

Tags: the-witcher

For this quest, I've been told to go see Coleman.  However, he is dead and his corpse has vanished, so there's no info there. Have I completely broken the quest somehow, making it incompletable? The wiki says this only happens if I talk to him before Kalkstein, but I never talked to Coleman ever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually that should be normal. The quest shouldn't be broken and should advance naturally when you get to the next stage.

Comment: Will I find out the next stage by chance, or do I have to do something out of the ordinary? I'm not getting told what to do next.

Comment: This is a huge quest, spanning across chapters. Just talk to people, it will advance eventually.

Comment: Coleman can be killed before you talk to him depending on choices you made earlier in the story.  But don't worry, in the end you didn't really need him anyway.